# While loop python glitch

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal

I have recently been doing a gamedev class in my high school and we have been using Mac's terminal to run python coding to make a text based game. I think it's a version of python 2.7 and I have encountered an error

```
while Menuselect != "play":
    MenuSelect = raw_input("Type 'quit' to exit - 'credits' for credits - Type 'play' to start\n")
    MenuSelect = MenuSelect.lower()
    if MenuSelect == "quit":
        SystemExit(0)
    elif MenuSelect == "credits":
        print("Lmao, only Matt made this")
    else:
        print("You mistyped. 10/10")

print(": You wake up in a dark room, you don't know where you are or how you got here :")
```

When I try and run it and enter 'play' to stop the loop, it just continues the loop again. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Menuselect is not the same as MenuSelect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are checking the variable name "Menuselect" with lowercase "s", but assigning the raw_input to a variable called "MenuSelect" with capital "S". Change the 'while' statement to

```
while MenuSelect != "play":
```

and it should work.